# Getting whois through socket

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to make simple code to do a whois lookup.  I am using 2 libraries

Get ip address: https://github.com/MichaCo/DnsClient.NET

Make socket connection: https://github.com/nterry/AwesomeSockets

I have just combined the basic examples.

This is my code:

```
using AwesomeSockets.Buffers;
using AwesomeSockets.Domain.Sockets;
using AwesomeSockets.Sockets;
using DnsClient;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

namespace WhoisSocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lookup = new LookupClient();
            var result = lookup.QueryAsync("whois.verisign-grs.com", QueryType.ANY).Result;

            var record = result.Answers.ARecords().FirstOrDefault();
            var address = record?.Address;

            //Client-side code
            ISocket server = AweSock.TcpConnect(address.ToString(), 43);

            AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer inBuf = AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer.New();
            AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer outBuf = AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer.New();

            //Lets send some data to the server! Make a Buffer object and populate it with some data like so:
            AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer.ClearBuffer(outBuf);
            AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer.Add(outBuf, "google.com");  // i also tried with \r\n
            AwesomeSockets.Buffers.Buffer.FinalizeBuffer(outBuf);

            //Now lets send it to the server!
            int bytesSent = AweSock.SendMessage(server, outBuf);

            //And receive any inbound messages as well. Received datga will be stored in inBuf. 
            Tuple<int, EndPoint> received = AweSock.ReceiveMessage(server, inBuf);


            var test = received.Item2.ToString();

            server.Close();

            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }
}
```

In `received` there isn't the expected data.  I manually used telnet to connect and send domain and it worked fine so I must have done something wrong but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: You are going in to a untrix operating system which only requires a '\r' (0x0D).  The code posted doesn't send a return so you do not get anything back.  When you tried "\r\n" you sent 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x0D which sent two returns so you may be getting back the results from the 2nd return which is over writing the response you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks good catch.  I tried it with \r and same result.  I think maybe I am not reading the data right.  The github sample was unclear.